# Using Scala's foldRight to evaluate polynomial

Tags: scala

I am having difficulty understanding why this code does not work. I have a polynomial 1 + 3x + 2x^2, which I represent as a list (1.0, 3.0, 2.0). To avoid powering up numbers with decimals to high indexes, I evaluate the polynomial as follows:
1 + x(3 + x(2))

For higher polynomials it would be a0 + x (a1 + x (a2 + x (a3 + ...)))...)

This can be conveniently evaluated right to left, and while I can easily write a loop, I thought Scala's fold operator might be useful. So I tried this on the Scala prompt but got the wrong answer (it should be 28.0)

```
scala> List(1.0, 3.0, 2.0).tail.foldRight(0.0)((a,x) => 3.0 * a + x)
res53: Double = 15.0
```

Here is how I expect the calculation on the fold to go:

3 * 0 + 2 = 2

3 * 2 + 3 = 9

3 * 9 + 1 = 28

Have I misunderstood the fold operator, or is there something trivial I missed? Thanks!

Edit; got it:

```
scala> List(1.0, 3.0, 2.0).foldRight(0.0)((a,x) => 3.0 * x + a)
res68: Double = 28.0
```

Comment: Got the answer; I should not be using tail, and I should be flipping the two arguments in the anonymous function, edited in the original post.

Comment: You might also use `reduceRight` instead of `foldRight`, and then you don't need to provide the `0.0` argument.  You could even use the underscore syntactic sugar with: `List(1.0, 3.0, 2.0).reduceRight(_ + 3.0 * _)`

Answer (score 3):

Using `tail` doesn't fold it as you describe in the steps above since it skips `1.0`. Also, swap the arguments `x` and `a`.

```
scala> List(1.0, 3.0, 2.0).foldRight(0.0)((x,a) => 3.0 * a + x)
res34: Double = 28.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding the first argument in my earlier attempts, and forgot to remove the tail. And come to think of it, I should remember the swap easily now - in fold right, the accumulated value is the right side value, i.e. (x, a) , and in fold left, the left side value, i.e. (a, x). And that is intuitive.